# Script / Utility to consolidate browser tabs?

Tags: .net, windows, internet-explorer, firefox

I often find I have 10 browser windows (some firefox, some ie) running, each with multiple tabs.  I'd like to be able to:
1) Consolidate all the URL's into a list, suitable for emailing
2) Merge all the tabs into one instance of either FF or IE

Anyone ever come across a utility like this, and if not, have any idea how a person might do something like:

```
for each browser as WebBrowser in allRunningApps  
   for each tab as browserTab in browser.Tabs  
      'do something with tab.url  
   next  
next
```

EDIT:  Ya I know you can get addons and what not to do some additional stuff with tabs, but thet is only marginally better than just manually copy/pasting links.  I am looking for a script/code/utility solution that does everything in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of June 2012, I still know of no utility that can do this.

I have found one add-in for Firefox that can copy all open tab url's to the clipboard (and vice versa), but nothing that will work across all browser windows, and definitely nothing that will work across multiple different browsers (ie, firefox, chrome, etc).

Answer (score 0):

IEPro for IE, or one of the countless FireFox extensions should be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I find myself using Google Chrome most recently and you can drag tabs between instances.  It's mighty handy.  I'd guess that there may be a Firefox extension that will add this handy feature.  You're not going to get very far with IE on this front, I don't think.  If you find an extension for Firefox that will handle this for you and still need to use IE, you can also get the [IETab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419) extension so you can use IE within Firefox.